# Help identify an old board game with three rooms in a castle and a ghost

Tags: identify-this-game

Some things that I can remember:

- There is a castle with 3 rooms. There are tree treasures in each of the rooms
- Maximum about 4 players
- Someone plays as a Ghost and others as people
- Ghost is hunting on humans and may kill them
- There are some cards with some actions, players should do that actions
- Goal: visit all three rooms in a castle, gather 3 treasures from each and leave the castle. Ghost's goal: kill all people before they leave the castle with treasures.
- Gameplay: each player roll the dice, moves his chip on a map. Some cells may has some specific rules (extramoves, take a card. etc).
- Initially I played it in Belarus and I'm not sure if it was just a localized version of an existing game or if it was invented there and is only played in Ex-USSR region.

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today this game is selling under name **Король-призрак** ("Ghost King"), but the design and rules have changed a little.

As I remember it, there were 4 ghosts with the different colors (white, yellow, red and blue) and abilities.

Picture of the board from [here:](https://www.mosigra.ru/king-ghost/)

[image]

And a different design [here:](https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/11643059/detail.aspx)

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to [BoardGames.SE].  I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include some pictures of the playing board. (The changes will not be visible until they're approved by other users, though.)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be [Le Fantôme des Mac Gregor](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/170496/le-fantome-des-mac-gregor) 
Since this one appears to have been published in 2005 this is probably a reprint and might have some rule changes.

Comment: Can you explain the similarities? From the look of the board, I don't see any similarities.

Comment: The link didn't have a picture.   But the rules were almost identical to those described by the original poster.  Chances are that the board was redesigned later

Comment: I don't think that is the same game since there was [a 1998 version that has a very radically different board design](http://www.jedisjeux.net/le-fantome-de-macgregor-g-1224.html)

Comment: Bowlturner it seems as though whoever wrote up that page you're citing might have game and title mixed up. The rules described on that page are nearly identical, but the game looks exactly like https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1326/macgregor (as pointed out by Pow-Ian). Those rules are available online and are very different from the one you're citing.

Comment: @freekvd Ah, that makes sense.  How did boardgamegeek allow that mistake to stay I wonder?